# Amazon Instace Ec2 Connection Timeout

Tags: amazon-ec2

I am using Amazon EC2 services & and its working correctly but suddenly from 3-days before when we try to access our instance using ssh connection we got folllowing error :

"ssh: connect to host ec2----**.compute-1.amazonaws.com port *: Connection timed out"

when I try to access our sites deployed on our EC2 instance , I received the same error , "The connection has timed out The server at ec2----***.compute-1.amazonaws.com is taking too long to respond"

there is no problem in network connection from our side as we are able to access other web site and services smoothly...

Can anyone plz help me or give me any suggestion regarding this.....as I can can't even able to access hosted site without this

Regards, Naveen

Comment: Reboot an EC2 instance?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your EC2 instance may have crashed? If you've touched nothing at all and you can't access it now it could be a possibility.

Try to check the console messages from the instance from your AWS control panel.

Also make sure that the security group the instance belongs to have all the right configuration to let you access the machine, if you've changed the security group that could make your instance unreachable from outside.

Comment: Thanks for replay ,I checked the security details as below.I thing there is no security issues.Please guide me If any thing I can do. 
All icmp -1 -1 0.0.0.0/0  -- Remove 
 -  udp 161 162 0.0.0.0/0  -- Remove 
SSH tcp 22 22 0.0.0.0/0  -- Remove 
HTTPS tcp 443 443 0.0.0.0/0  -- Remove 
HTTP tcp 80 80 0.0.0.0/0  -- Remove

Comment: Yeah looks like your security group is fine, so I assume that the instance has crashed (sad, but it happens), have a look at the Console messages from the instance  (you can do so in the AWS panel) and check what it says

Comment: Hi I have  pasted the console log in the below   url     http://pastie.org/1514490. Please can you look into that and tell me what problem I am facing and how can I resolve this. sorry ,because I am new to the amazon ec2           thanks in advance

Comment: Don't see any issues in the console log either, try rebooting the instance, also try to contact Amazon to ask if the hardware under the instance have been affected by something, sometimes they kill instances on the spot if the hardware fails

Comment: Although I must say if they do that they warn you in advance with a nice email :)

Comment: ok thanks for the information.I will contact the amazon people

Answer (score 0):

The security group "Default" is damaged on AWS, it´s necessary to remove all inbound rules and recreate. As the example below:

- Create a new rule: All TCP, source 0.0.0.0/0, click "add Rule" and then "Apply Rule Changes"

However, your server will be at security risk, because all TCP ports are open.